# how to increase the height of navigation bar and change the color of status bar in xcode 8 using swift3?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to change the height of the navigation bar, so that I can add the search bar field in it. As the background color of my navigation bar is purple I want to change the color of status bar (data carrier, date and battery widget on the top of the screen) to white instead of black. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at this sample app, as it explains how to modify the UINavigationBar.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/NavBar/Introduction/Intro.html

To change status bar to white, add this to your ViewController.

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {

    return .lightContent
}
```